# cksum command doesn't recognize -a option

Tags: bash, gnu, checksum, gnu-coreutils

I'm trying to automate checksum generation with CRC32, SHA1, and SHA256 algorithms on a directory of files, and I'm getting errors from cksum (v.8.32)

According to the cksum [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cksum-invocation.html) at gnu.org, it recognizes the option `-a` or `--algorithm` to choose from a list of supported checksum algorithms (including sha1, sha256, and crc), but it does not appear to be working.

The command:

```
cksum -a sha1 foo.txt
```

Gives the error message:

```
cksum: invalid option -- 'a'
Try 'cksum --help' for more information.
```

I tried running `cksum --help`, but it only prints the following:

```
Usage: cksum [FILE]...
  or:  cksum [OPTION]
Print CRC checksum and byte counts of each FILE.

      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

GNU coreutils online help: <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/cksum>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) cksum invocation'
```

And the resources it points me to are not helpful.

What is going wrong? Is there a better approach to take?

Comment: The GNU commands are `cksum` `sha1sum` `sha256sum`

Comment: According to the manual cksum should be able to do all of them

Comment: It may be so for a recent `cksum`; what Linux are you using?

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need GNU Coreutils >= 9.0 (i.e. `cksum` version >= 9.0)

Here's what the changelog for version 9.0 says:

> cksum now supports the -a option to select any digest.